# Conectar container php + container Apache + container mysql sem docker-compose

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker

Tenho acesso a um servidor Linux e nele não tenho acesso a internet. Possuo apenas o docker sem o docker-compose instalado, e tenho 3 imagens já carregadas no docker(apache, php e mysql).
Cada imagem está rodando em um container. Como posso integrar os 3 containers para rodar aplicações web?

Comment: Pra que exatamente vc precisa do apache ? só com o php vc consegue criar um localhost..

Comment: Sempre usei apache e php nas minhas aplicações web, n tenho conhecimento se com apenas o php eu consiga rodar uma aplicação. É preciso de um servidor web, não ?

Comment: Pelo oq eu estou vendo, o seu caso, só o PHP e mysql resolve. Vc tem o codigo fonte ? Se tiver, faz o experimento, instala o PHP e configura o path, vai até a pasta do codigo fonte e manda `php -S localhost:8000` esse comando significa que vc está criando um servidor no seu localhost com a porta 8000, daí basta acessar o browser `localhost:8000`

Answer (score 0):

Bom, olhando para o seu problema, me parece que vc não precisa do container do apache, já que com o do PHP vc consegui instanciar um servidor da seguinte forma: `php -S localhost:8000`. Partindo dessa ideia, vc só precisa o container do PHP e do MYSQL, vamos tratar um por vez.

**Container do MYSQL.**
Aqui é simples, vc só precisa instanciar o container normalmente, só nao esquece de mapear a porta com `-p 3306:3306`, ela vai ser util.

**Container do PHP**
Seu código fonte precisa estar aqui dentro, e entao você instanciar o servidor por linha de comando, como eu disse em cima. Alguns pontos precisam ser notados, para você se conectar ao container no mysql, no host vc precisa apontar o IP do container do MYSQL e na porta, a porta que você definiu (no caso de cima, seria a 3306), você pode descobrir o IP do container dando um `docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID>`. Isso já deve bastar para conectar um ao outro.

Para facilitar a sua vida você pode fazer algumas coisas, por exemplo:

Você pode mapear um volume para nao precisar ficar rebuildando a imagem toda vez que mudar o código, na instanciação do container do PHP você pode mandar uma flag passando esse parametro `-v <SUA_PASTA_LOCAL>:<PASTA_DO_CONTAINER_COM_CODIGO>`

Outra dica, é usar variaveis de ambiente. Com váriaveis de ambiente você nao vai precisar ficar mudando a conexão do banco sempre que o ip do container mudar, dentro do código do php vc pode capturar essas variaveis usando `getenv('exemplo')`. E no hora de instanciar esse container, voĉe pode passar o valor dessa variavel, assim,  `-e exemplo:valor_da_variavel_exemplo`.